# Oauth2: is the refresh token limited to the app that generated it or not?

Tags: oauth-2.0

If i've an application, and I use its `app_id` and `app_secret` to login and get an `access_token` and a `refresh_token` back.

The `refresh_token` can be used by any application or just by the one that created it?

Similarly, if the app is public (it does not require  the usage of `app_secret`) is still the `refresh_token` linked to the application or can it be freely used by any other app?

Answer (score 0):

A refresh token is associated to a client (and also to a specific user when applicable). Typically the Authorization Server will store details such as `client_id`, `sub`, refresh token hash, expiry and revocation status in a database table called something like `delegations`.

When  a client sends a [refresh token grant](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/) message, the `client_id` must also be sent:

- For public clients, anyone who can get hold of a refresh token can send the request
- For confidential clients, a client secret must also be provided. This can be a string value or a stronger credential, such as a client certificate.

In both cases the Authorization Server will typically use the received details to find the database row, return an error if the token is expired, revoked etc, or otherwise return a fresh access token. This [article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-refresh/) provides a good overview with sone further info.